# How to run 3 queries using single connection, command and reader in NpgSql

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core-mvc, npgsql, .net-6.0

**controller:**

```
using (NpgsqlConnection connection2 = new NpgsqlConnection(connString))
        {
            connection2.Open();
            NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(null, connection2);

            command.CommandText =
                "SELECT a.account_name,a.type, DATE(t.date),t.transaction_id,t.amount,t.note FROM transaction AS t INNER JOIN account AS a ON t.account_id = a.account_id WHERE t.date BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate ORDER BY t.date";
           command.CommandText =
                "SELECT SUM(t.amount) as income,a.type FROM transaction AS t INNER JOIN account AS a ON t.account_id = a.account_id WHERE a.type = 'income' AND t.date BETWEEN @startDate and @endDate GROUP BY a.type";
            command.CommandText =
                "SELECT SUM(t.amount) as expense,a.type FROM transaction AS t INNER JOIN account AS a ON t.account_id = a.account_id WHERE a.type = 'expense' AND t.date BETWEEN @startDate and @endDate GROUP BY a.type";
            NpgsqlParameter startDateParam = new NpgsqlParameter("@startDate", NpgsqlDbType.Date, 0);
            NpgsqlParameter endDateParam = new NpgsqlParameter("@endDate", NpgsqlDbType.Date, 0);

            startDateParam.Value = startDate;
            endDateParam.Value = endDate;

            command.Parameters.Add(startDateParam);
            command.Parameters.Add(endDateParam);

            command.Prepare();
            NpgsqlDataReader reader2 = command.ExecuteReader();

            List<Transaction> allTransactionLists = new List<Transaction>();

            List<Transaction> incomeLists = new List<Transaction>();
            List<Transaction> expenseLists = new List<Transaction>();

            if (reader2.HasRows)

            {

                while (reader2.Read())

                {

                    allTransactionLists.Add(new Transaction

                    {

                        TransactionId = Convert.ToInt32(reader2["transaction_id"]),

                        AccountName = Convert.ToString(reader2["account_name"]),

                        Type = Convert.ToString(reader2["type"]),

                        Date = Convert.ToDateTime(reader2["date"]),

                        Amount = Convert.ToInt32(reader2["amount"]),

                    });

                }

            }
```

In this, I wanted to run three queries using **command.Text**, but by using that only the last query will execute.

I want to execute all 3 queries and use them separately, but with a single **connection, command, and reader**

How can I do that?

Comment: Perhaps you should combine the results using a UNION. Take a look at: [PostgreSQL UNION](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-union/)

Comment: What are you trying to return? All transactions and the grand total of `income` and `expense` repeated on every transaction? Or the transactions and grand totals separately?

Comment: I am trying to return a model like this: 
`var model = new AllTransactionViewModel();
model.AllTransactions = allTransactionLists;
model.IncomeLists = incomeLists;
model.ExpenseLists = expenseLists;

return View(model);`

Comment: There are different number of columns so cannot use UNION I have to run all queries seperately.

Comment: The firt query is used to filter transaction details between dates
2nd query to caluculate sum of amount if it is a income type
3rd query to caluculate sum of amount if it is a expense type

Comment: Please don't keep asking the same question over and over and over again

Answer (score 0):

The queries are :

```
SELECT a.account_name,a.type, DATE(t.date),t.transaction_id,t.amount,t.note
FROM transaction AS t 
    INNER JOIN account AS a ON t.account_id = a.account_id 
WHERE t.date BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate 
ORDER BY t.date;

SELECT SUM(t.amount) as income,a.type 
FROM transaction AS t 
    INNER JOIN account AS a ON t.account_id = a.account_id 
WHERE a.type = 'income' 
    AND t.date BETWEEN @startDate and @endDate 
GROUP BY a.type;

SELECT SUM(t.amount) as expense,a.type 
FROM transaction AS t 
    INNER JOIN account AS a ON t.account_id = a.account_id 
WHERE a.type = 'expense' 
    AND t.date BETWEEN @startDate and @endDate 
GROUP BY a.type;
```

It looks like you want to return all transactions along with the grand totals for `income` and `expense` accounts.

If you only wanted to return the income and expense grand totals you could write a single query:

```
SELECT SUM(t.amount) as expense,a.type 
FROM transaction AS t 
    INNER JOIN account AS a ON t.account_id = a.account_id 
WHERE a.type in ('expense','income')
    AND t.date BETWEEN @startDate and @endDate 
GROUP BY a.type;
```

This query returns two rows only, one for `income` and one for `expense`.

You can use [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper) to avoid writing all that boilerplate code and write just:

```
using var connection2 = new NpgsqlConnection(connString);

var totalSQL= @"SELECT SUM(t.amount) as total,a.type 
FROM transaction AS t 
    INNER JOIN account AS a ON t.account_id = a.account_id 
WHERE a.type in ('expense','income')
    AND t.date BETWEEN @startDate and @endDate 
GROUP BY a.type;";

var results=connection2.Query(totalSql,new {startDate,endDate});
```

The `totalSQL` is defined using a verbatim literal which allows newlines. This makes it a lot cleaner to write the query.

`Query` returns an `IEnumerable<T>`. When a type isn't specified, `it returns` IEnumerable`which allows using`ToDictionary` and retrieve amounts by type :

```
var results=connection2.Query(totalSql,new {startDate,endDate})
                       .ToDictionary(r=>r.type,r=>r.total);

var income=results["income"];
```

Another option is to create a type, eg a record, just for the results :

```
record TypeTotal(string type,decimal total);
...
var results=connection2.Query<TypeTotal>(totalSql,new {startDate,endDate})
                       .ToDictionary(r=>r.type,r=>r.total);

var income=results["income"];
```

The individual transactions can be retrieved the same way:

```
record Transaction(string AccountName, string Type, 
   DateTime Date, decimal Amount,long TransactionId, string Note);

...
var txSql=@"SELECT a.account_name,a.type, DATE(t.date),t.transaction_id,
                   t.amount,t.note
FROM transaction AS t 
    INNER JOIN account AS a ON t.account_id = a.account_id 
WHERE t.date BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate 
ORDER BY t.date;";

var transactions=connection2.Query<Transaction>(txSql,new {startDate,endDate}).AsList();
```